# Does the vector space of the infinitely differentiable functions belongs to the space $\nabla H^1(\Omega)$?

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, differential-geometry, vector-analysis, sobolev-spaces

Let $\Omega\subset \mathbb R^3$ be a bounded lipschitz domain.
Denote by $H^1(\Omega)$ the usual Sobolev space and by $(C^{\infty}(\Omega))^3$ the vector space of the infinitely differentiable functions.
Then, do we have the following inclusion
$$
(C^{\infty}(\Omega))^3 \subset \nabla H^1(\Omega)?
$$
Thanks.

Comment: What are you defining $\nabla H^1(\Omega) $ to be here?

Comment: @K.Power $\nabla H1(\Omega)=\{u=\nabla f | f\in H^1(\Omega)\}$

Comment: Are all your functions real valued here?

Comment: @K.Power Yes yes